# How do I get touch working in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an Android app with Unity3D and it works with click detection already, but not with touch. I need touch though for multitouch detection.

What I want: I have my player and 2 images of arrows. One arrow points right and one left. When I touch the left arrow the player should start moving left, when I touch the right arrow the player should start moving right.

But how do I detect which arrow is touched (and held)? All the code I found on Google is too old and not working anymore.

I'm working with C# scripts and it's a 2D game.

Comment: Detecting touch is easy. Detecting touch and held requires you know C# well because there are lots of logic involved. Provide the code that doesn't work then maybe some one can help you.

Comment: I just realised, friend @Klausar is describing ............................ *a button!!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Klausar, what you're looking for is .........

## A BUTTON (!!!)

it's that easy!

1. click "add Canvas".  (You very likely want "scale to screen size" - select that option.)
2. click "add Button".
3. there is no "three" .. go drinking.

In your code, have a routine like this for the right-side button

```
public void UserClickedRight()
 {
 Debug.Log("click right whoo!");
 }
```

and have a similar routine for the left-side button.

## 1. Go to your `Button` in the editor.

## 2. Simply drag the script to it and select `UserClickedRight` !!

You actually do not have to program buttons from scratch :)

This is a basic mechanism of Unity - drag a game object to a "slot" for it in the Editor.

(The game object you drag, has the script in question on it.)

You DO NOT need to go to the level of touch handling to achieve a button!

---

## Now you ask, what about "when holding down on the button"?

It's very easy, you just need to know a couple of things about the Unity "event" system.

In `Button`, Unity have done all the work for "OnClick":

[image]

Since "click" is common, they put that one right in the Inspector panel for you for convenience.

The good news is that `Button` has **many more events you can use**.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html

My guess is you want to use `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` in your case.

To use the other events (which Unity did not bother putting in the Inspector panel) is very simple, you just

## 1, make a script that references the events you want,

and,

## 2, you put that script ON the button in question ...

it's that easy.

Step by step explanation:

You're going to be using Unity's event system, so:

```
  using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
```

Next. You know that a script normally starts like this...

```
 public class FancyButton:MonoBehaviour
```

The "MonoBehaviour" part just means that it's a c# script which will be "driving a GameObject".

In this case we have to further alert the engine that you will be using those click events. So you add this.

```
,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
```

So far we have this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FancyButton:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
    {
```

Now the easy part.

You just type the two routines which Unity will run for you, when, those things happen.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FancyButton:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{
  public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
  {
      Debug.Log("holy! someone put the pointer down!")
  }

  public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
  {
      Debug.Log("whoa! someone let go!")
  }
}
```

Now all you have to do is drop that script on the Button. Done!

You can put that script on any button, where, you need that functionality.

Next, click on Obi-wan to see where we're at so far!

[image]

Finally, it sounds like you want to do something "when the button is being held down". That's just a general programming issue - **you'd have a boolean which you turn on and off as the button goes up and down**. Let's do it.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
    
    public class FancyButton:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
        {
        [System.NonSerialized] public bool mouseIsDownRightNow;
        
        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
            {
            mouseIsDownRightNow = true;
            }
        
        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
            {
            mouseIsDownRightNow = false;
            }
        }
```

You could access that variable from another script, or whatever you want.

Add the following if you want to run a routine while the button is down:

```
    void Update()
        {
        if (buttonIsDownRightNow) WhileButtonIsDown();
        }
    private void WhileButtonIsDown()
        {
        Debug.Log("THE BUTTON IS DOWN! WHOA!");
        }
```

Try that and watch the console as you hold the button down and up.

Here's an example of something like continually increasing a value while the button is down:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FancyButton:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
    {
    [System.NonSerialized] public bool buttonIsDownRightNow;
    private int countSomething;
    
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
        {
        buttonIsDownRightNow = true;
        }
    
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
        {
        buttonIsDownRightNow = false;
        }
    
    private void WhileButtonIsDown()
        {
        ++countSomething;
        }
    
    void Update()
        {
        if (buttonIsDownRightNow) WhileButtonIsDown();
        
        Debug.Log("value is now " +countSomething.ToString());
        }
    }
```

That's all there is to it.  Once you really understand events in Unity, there is not much more to learn about Unity.

The only other important topics are Mecanim, shader writing, touch, coroutines, threading, PhysX, native plugins, sprites, networking, dynamic mesh, navigation, VR, AR, animation, inverse kinematics, particles, terrain, IAP, lighting, baking, shadows, MMP, character controllers, and audio. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! So multitouch already works in this example? For example if I have a button to shoot and to walk left, can I press both at the same time?

Comment: YES, go for it.  Unity's UI system is really great.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that and it worked. However, I can't hold down the button, it only detects the MouseDown. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @Fattie Thanks Fattie, but what is the efficient way to run the code without using update and spoiling the fency button script. like i want to carry out two task on two sate of the bool buttonIsDownRightNow but only once.

Answer (score 0):

You should firsty read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html).
What you are trying to do is actually simple:

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        if (guiTexture1.HitTest(touch.position)) {

            // Maybe move left
        }
        if (guiTexture2.HitTest(touch.position)) {

            // Maybe move right
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: this code now checks which image is being pressed
Edit 2: Added multitouch support

Comment: This would have worked if he just wanted to detect touch/help on the screen. He wants to detect touch on two different arrows. This code has no way of determine which arrow is being touched.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps me. Does multitouch in this example already work? And can I also use a gameObject instead of a GUI Object?

Comment: I re-edited my code, now it check for every touch in Input.touches. If you want to test if a GameObject is "touched" by the user, you can use Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position))

Comment: unfortunately **none of this will work** if you have a UI layer (as you almost certainly do), you have to totally redo everything now for that hassle.  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/784617/how-do-i-block-touch-events-from-propagating-throu.html